Wifi connects but no internet access on Ubuntu, works fine with Windows dual boot
I have my desktop dual boot with Windows and Ubuntu 22.04. I have faced this issue before, but earlier it just went away. The issue is, my spectrum wifi connects to all devices including Windows on the same device, but not on Ubuntu. It used to be working for over a year but due to some reason it just stopped working.
I would like some input on how I can diagnose this. Also it gets connected in a weird way. When I restart my network services, I can access the internet for a brief time and then it goes dark. Also the wifi connects, but I am not able to access any websites.
This is the output of inxi -N:
Network:
  Device-1: Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 3168NGW [Stone Peak] driver: iwlwifi
  Device-2: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet
    driver: r8169

Edit:
Adding information suggested by @waltinator
Output of journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager
Apr 16 19:10:03 nevin-ubuntu NetworkManager[1111]: <info>  [1713309003.5971] manager: rfkill: Wi-Fi hardware radio set enabled
Apr 16 19:10:03 nevin-ubuntu NetworkManager[1111]: <info>  [1713309003.6725] audit: op="radio-control" arg="wireless-enabled:on" pid=2561 uid=1000 result="success"
Apr 16 19:10:03 nevin-ubuntu NetworkManager[1111]: <info>  [1713309003.6726] manager: rfkill: Wi-Fi now enabled by radio killswitch
Apr 16 19:10:03 nevin-ubuntu NetworkManager[1111]: <info>  [1713309003.6917] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: internal-starting -> disconnected
Apr 16 19:10:03 nevin-ubuntu NetworkManager[1111]: <info>  [1713309003.6918] device (p2p-dev-wlp3s0): state change: unavailable -> unmanaged (reason 'removed', sys-iface-state: 'removed')
Apr 16 19:10:03 nevin-ubuntu NetworkManager[1111]: <info>  [1713309003.6920] Wi-Fi P2P device controlled by interface wlp3s0 created
Apr 16 19:10:03 nevin-ubuntu NetworkManager[1111]: <info>  [1713309003.6921] manager: (p2p-dev-wlp3s0): new 802.11 Wi-Fi P2P device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/14)
Apr 16 19:10:03 nevin-ubuntu NetworkManager[1111]: <info>  [1713309003.6922] device (p2p-dev-wlp3s0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Apr 16 19:10:03 nevin-ubuntu NetworkManager[1111]: <info>  [1713309003.6923] device (wlp3s0): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'supplicant-available', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Apr 16 19:10:03 nevin-ubuntu NetworkManager[1111]: <info>  [1713309003.6925] device (p2p-dev-wlp3s0): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Apr 16 19:10:06 nevin-ubuntu NetworkManager[1111]: <info>  [1713309006.8374] policy: auto-activating connection '**WIFI SSID**' (f9a1c045-a5c5-404b-bc6f-3486b5fb5494)
Apr 16 19:10:06 nevin-ubuntu NetworkManager[1111]: <info>  [1713309006.8376] device (wlp3s0): Activation: starting connection '**WIFI SSID**' (f9a1c045-a5c5-404b-bc6f-3486b5fb5494)
Apr 16 19:10:06 nevin-ubuntu NetworkManager[1111]: <info>  [1713309006.8376] device (wlp3s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Apr 16 19:10:06 nevin-ubuntu NetworkManager[1111]: <info>  [1713309006.8377] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Apr 16 19:10:06 nevin-ubuntu NetworkManager[1111]: <info>  [1713309006.8378] device (wlp3s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Apr 16 19:10:06 nevin-ubuntu NetworkManager[1111]: <info>  [1713309006.8379] device (wlp3s0): Activation: (wifi) access point '**WIFI SSID**' has security, but secrets are required.
Apr 16 19:10:06 nevin-ubuntu NetworkManager[1111]: <info>  [1713309006.8379] device (wlp3s0): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Apr 16 19:10:06 nevin-ubuntu NetworkManager[1111]: <info>  [1713309006.8382] device (wlp3s0): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Apr 16 19:10:06 nevin-ubuntu NetworkManager[1111]: <info>  [1713309006.8383] device (wlp3s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Apr 16 19:10:06 nevin-ubuntu NetworkManager[1111]: <info>  [1713309006.8384] device (wlp3s0): Activation: (wifi) connection '**WIFI SSID**' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
Apr 16 19:10:06 nevin-ubuntu NetworkManager[1111]: <info>  [1713309006.8384] Config: added 'ssid' value '**WIFI SSID**'
Apr 16 19:10:06 nevin-ubuntu NetworkManager[1111]: <info>  [1713309006.8384] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
Apr 16 19:10:06 nevin-ubuntu NetworkManager[1111]: <info>  [1713309006.8384] Config: added 'bgscan' value 'simple:30:-70:86400'
Apr 16 19:10:06 nevin-ubuntu NetworkManager[1111]: <info>  [1713309006.8384] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK WPA-PSK-SHA256 FT-PSK SAE FT-SAE'
Apr 16 19:10:06 nevin-ubuntu NetworkManager[1111]: <info>  [1713309006.8384] Config: added 'auth_alg' value 'OPEN'
Apr 16 19:10:06 nevin-ubuntu NetworkManager[1111]: <info>  [1713309006.8384] Config: added 'psk' value '<hidden>'
Apr 16 19:10:06 nevin-ubuntu NetworkManager[1111]: <info>  [1713309006.8471] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> associating
Apr 16 19:10:06 nevin-ubuntu NetworkManager[1111]: <info>  [1713309006.8471] device (p2p-dev-wlp3s0): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> associating
Apr 16 19:10:06 nevin-ubuntu NetworkManager[1111]: <info>  [1713309006.8646] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> associated
Apr 16 19:10:06 nevin-ubuntu NetworkManager[1111]: <info>  [1713309006.8646] device (p2p-dev-wlp3s0): supplicant management interface state: associating -> associated
Apr 16 19:10:07 nevin-ubuntu NetworkManager[1111]: <info>  [1713309007.0646] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: associated -> completed
Apr 16 19:10:07 nevin-ubuntu NetworkManager[1111]: <info>  [1713309007.0646] device (wlp3s0): Activation: (wifi) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful. Connected to wireless network "**WIFI SSID**"
Apr 16 19:10:07 nevin-ubuntu NetworkManager[1111]: <info>  [1713309007.0646] device (p2p-dev-wlp3s0): supplicant management interface state: associated -> completed
Apr 16 19:10:07 nevin-ubuntu NetworkManager[1111]: <info>  [1713309007.0647] device (wlp3s0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Apr 16 19:10:07 nevin-ubuntu NetworkManager[1111]: <info>  [1713309007.0650] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Apr 16 19:10:07 nevin-ubuntu NetworkManager[1111]: <info>  [1713309007.0786] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): state changed new lease, address=**IP ADDRESS**
Apr 16 19:10:07 nevin-ubuntu NetworkManager[1111]: <info>  [1713309007.0796] device (wlp3s0): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Apr 16 19:10:07 nevin-ubuntu NetworkManager[1111]: <info>  [1713309007.1136] device (wlp3s0): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Apr 16 19:10:07 nevin-ubuntu NetworkManager[1111]: <info>  [1713309007.1137] device (wlp3s0): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Apr 16 19:10:07 nevin-ubuntu NetworkManager[1111]: <info>  [1713309007.1139] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Apr 16 19:10:07 nevin-ubuntu NetworkManager[1111]: <info>  [1713309007.1142] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
Apr 16 19:10:07 nevin-ubuntu NetworkManager[1111]: <info>  [1713309007.1142] policy: set '**WIFI SSID**' (wlp3s0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS
Apr 16 19:10:07 nevin-ubuntu NetworkManager[1111]: <info>  [1713309007.1145] device (wlp3s0): Activation: successful, device activated.
Apr 16 19:10:07 nevin-ubuntu NetworkManager[1111]: <info>  [1713309007.1755] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL

Output of service NetworkManager status
● NetworkManager.service - Network Manager
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Tue 2024-04-16 18:51:01 EDT; 5min ago
       Docs: man:NetworkManager(8)
   Main PID: 1090 (NetworkManager)
      Tasks: 3 (limit: 18896)
     Memory: 10.3M
        CPU: 378ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/NetworkManager.service
             └─1090 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

Apr 16 18:55:54 user NetworkManager[1090]: <info>  [1713308154.7313] manager: (veth57d3ce4): new Veth device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/11)
Apr 16 18:55:54 user NetworkManager[1090]: <info>  [1713308154.7317] device (veth57d3ce4): carrier: link connected
Apr 16 18:55:54 user NetworkManager[1090]: <info>  [1713308154.7317] device (veth7b01fc9): carrier: link connected
Apr 16 18:55:54 user NetworkManager[1090]: <info>  [1713308154.7318] device (br-3f0f9c4dc79a): carrier: link connected
Apr 16 18:55:54 user NetworkManager[1090]: <info>  [1713308154.7583] device (veth7b01fc9): released from master device br-3f0f9c4dc79a
Apr 16 18:55:54 user NetworkManager[1090]: <info>  [1713308154.8263] manager: (veth27a7d2c): new Veth device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/12)
Apr 16 18:55:54 user NetworkManager[1090]: <info>  [1713308154.8268] manager: (vetha56c493): new Veth device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/13)
Apr 16 18:55:54 user NetworkManager[1090]: <info>  [1713308154.8273] device (veth27a7d2c): carrier: link connected
Apr 16 18:55:54 user NetworkManager[1090]: <info>  [1713308154.8274] device (vetha56c493): carrier: link connected
Apr 16 18:55:54 user NetworkManager[1090]: <info>  [1713308154.8275] device (br-3f0f9c4dc79a): carrier: link connected

And service --status-all
 [ + ]  acpid
 [ - ]  alsa-utils
 [ - ]  anacron
 [ + ]  apparmor
 [ + ]  apport
 [ + ]  avahi-daemon
 [ + ]  bluetooth
 [ + ]  connman
 [ - ]  console-setup.sh
 [ + ]  cron
 [ + ]  cups
 [ + ]  cups-browsed
 [ + ]  dbus
 [ + ]  docker
 [ + ]  gdm3
 [ - ]  grub-common
 [ - ]  hwclock.sh
 [ + ]  irqbalance
 [ + ]  kerneloops
 [ - ]  keyboard-setup.sh
 [ + ]  kmod
 [ + ]  lm-sensors
 [ + ]  openvpn
 [ - ]  plymouth
 [ + ]  plymouth-log
 [ + ]  procps
 [ - ]  pulseaudio-enable-autospawn
 [ - ]  rsync
 [ - ]  saned
 [ - ]  speech-dispatcher
 [ - ]  spice-vdagent
 [ + ]  udev
 [ + ]  ufw
 [ + ]  unattended-upgrades
 [ - ]  uuidd
 [ - ]  whoopsie
 [ - ]  x11-common


Your ixni -N shows 2 NICs, 1 wired, 1 wireless, each associated with its own kernel driver. Look at the network logs with the terminal command: sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager. Read man journalctl NetworkManager service. Also do: service NetworkManager status and service --status-all. Please [edit] your question to add whatever information you get. Do not use Add Comment.
